# QFT visual interpretation of $U(1)$

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, group-theory

Anyone has (even a "pictorial") way of visualize what the group $U(1)$ does on the fields in the QFT framework?

I know that $U(1)$ can be seen as a circle and the operation of the groups is basically a rotation of a certain angle along of the cirle.
But I don't know how to relate QFT with this visualization.

I also know that $U(1)$ invariance, implies from Noether theorem that there are quantities conserved which are called "charges" and that I can develop QED starting from $U(1)$ gauge invariance  (local phase transformations).

Basically I just need a visual idea of the field and what happens to it when I apply $U(1)$ transformations. Maybe the problem is that I don't know what a phase transformation actually is from a "visual" point of view.

Comment: Can you visualize multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: I mean a complex number can be seen as vector in the cartesian plane and I always thought that the multiplication of it by the exponential is just a rotation basically.  But I am not sure I  got the point of your question. Do you mean that is something abstract and I should leave it as it is?

Comment: And what's wrong with visualising ${\rm U(1)}$ as a circle? Suppose you have a field $\psi(x)$ that lives on the space-time manifold. If the field has internal ${\rm U(1)}$ symmetry, you *can* imagine that at all points $x$ of the space-time there is a circle, representing the phase of the field. This circle, of course, has nothing to do with directions in space-time; it exists in a separate, independent dimension. (*Technical note: this is useful for deriving the notion of covariant derivative and the "connection".*)

Comment: So you mean to associate to anypoint of this manifold a circle ? Sorry to repeat what you said I just want to check that I understood

Comment: Essentially, yes. If $x$ represent points on the source manifold, with $\psi(x)$ being the field at that point, then to every such point we have to associate a "circle" representing the $\rm U(1)$ transformation of the field at that point. Of course this "circle" does not live the "real" (configuration) space; it takes values in the abstract space representing the phase of the field at that point.

Comment: Okay and basically when I say that there's U(1) invariance, I m just saying that different "configurations" of the manifolds + abstract  point of circle are essentially the same. There's also something which to mean seems strange and that is the fact that in Quantum field theory fields are operator so I don't know what actually happens when I multiply it with a complex number such as the exp to i theta

Comment: You are confused by how an operator differs from itself times a phase? What do you do for matrices or differential operators?

Comment: I just multiply the matrices times the phase, so I guess it applies also here, am I right or I m just overthinking?

Comment: Yes, it applies here…